# Clear form field on change functionality removes form post value

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to prevent a user from not selecting a jquery autocomplete option. I have following code, which is working but when  I submit the form, the 'hidden_applinput_' + applid field value is removed. Below is the code

```
$(function() {
try {
    $("[id^=applinput_]").each(function(){
        app_id = this.id.split("_");
        id = app_id[1];

    $("#applinput_"+ id).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "cfc/cfc_App.cfc?method=getMethod&returnformat=json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    nameAppSearchString: request.term,
                    maxRows: 25,
                    style: "full",
                },

                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            })
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
                //separate id and checkbox
                app_selid = this.id.split("_");
                //separate id 
                applid = app_selid[1];  
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        $('#hidden_applinput_' + applid).val(ui.item.value);
        $('#typeinput_' + applid).val(ui.item.type);
        $('#hidden_typeinput_' + applid).val(ui.item.typeID);
        return false;
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                this.value = '';
                $('#hidden_applinput_' + applid).val('');
                }
            else{
             // return your label here
            }
        },
    })
})
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) 
    {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append('<a onmouseover=$("#span' + item.value + '").show(); onmouseout=$("#span' + item.value + '").hide();><span style="float:left;" >' + item.label + '</span><span  id="span' + item.value + '" style="float: right;height:inherit; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 0.3em; padding-right: 0.4em; padding-bottom: 0.3em; padding-left: 0.4em; display: none; cursor:pointer; " onclick=javascript:event.stopPropagation();showprofile("' + item.value + '");><!---view profile---></span><div style="clear:both; height:auto;"></div></a>')
        .appendTo( ul );
    };      
} catch(exception){}
});
```

The problem is in the change event

```
$('#hidden_applinput_' + applid).val('');
```

If I remove this the form will post the value. Is there another way to do this?

**EDIT**

I am adding some HTML code to help with this. I wish to keep this as simple as possible so please ask if there is more code you would like to see. This is an admin script so I do have to keep some things discreet. I am using Coldfusion along with jQuery. The relative HTML / CFM code is as follows.

```
<cfquery name="qApp2">
SELECT *
FROM AppType
WHERE (AppTypeID NOT IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Applist#" list="yes">))
ORDER BY AppOrder
</CFQUERY>
  <cfset index = 1>
  <cfloop query="qApp2">

  <!--- App Query --->
    <cfquery name="qMasterApp">
    SELECT *
    FROM App
    WHERE AppType = <cfqueryparam value="#AppTypeID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery>

  <h3 id="header_#index#">inactive - #AppType#</h3>
     <div>
        <p> 
            <!---- Serial Number --->
            <div class="ctrlHolder" id="serial_#index#"><label for="" class="serial" style="display:none"><em>*</em>Serial Number</label>
                <cfinput type="text"
                            name="app_#AppTypeID#_ser"
                            data-default-value="Enter Serial Number or Value"
                            size="35" 
                            class="textInput"
                            id="serialinput_#index#"
                            value=""  disabled />
                    <!---<cfinput name="app_#AppTypeID#_IDd" type="hidden" id="hserialinput_#index#" value="" disabled />--->
                  <p class="formHint">field is required</p>
            </div>
            <!--- App --->
            <div class="ctrlHolder" id="appl_#index#"><label for="" style="display:none"><em>*</em>App</label>
                <cfinput name="app_#AppTypeID#_app" 
                    data-default-value="App"
                    class="textInput AppSearch"
                    id="applinput_#index#"
                    value="" disabled>
                    <cfinput name="app_#AppTypeID#_IDd" type="hidden" class="hidden_AppSearch" id="hidden_applinput_#index#" value="" />

              <p class="formHint">App is required</p>
            </div>
            <!--- active --->
            <div class="ctrlHolder" id="color_select">
              <ul class="list">
                <li>
                <label for="agreement">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2_#index#" name="app_#AppTypeID#_chk" style="width:50px"> 
                active
                </label>

                </li>
                <li>
                <a class="dig3">[add an App]</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
       </p>
       </div>
      <cfset index = index + 1>
      <cfset Applist = ListAppend(Applist,AppTypeID)>
  </cfloop>
```

Comment: Post your relevant html code here

Comment: If you know JavaScript of any sort you should be not be using `cfform`

Comment: I am very green with jquery and JS.

Comment: Even though the hidden input has an id of `hidden_applinput_#index#`, its name is `app_#AppTypeID#_IDd`. Are you saying you are not seeing the `app_#AppTypeID#_IDd` field-value pair in the form post?

Comment: When the form is posted, app_#AppTypeID#_IDd's value does not show up on the receiving end of the post. When I change the type to "text" prior to posting, I can see the value after selecting the autocomplete selection. Somewhere between the submission and the script that receives the form post, I am losing the value if app_#AppTypeID#_IDd. It comes up empty. I suspect that I am losing with the "change" event.

Comment: I'd recommend removing cfinput/cfform, as it may be conflicting with your othe rcode. I'm not saying it will fix it, but you don't want CF's JS stuff getting in the way of your JS stuff.

Comment: Just another wild guess, but try changing `if (!ui.item) {` to `if (!ui.item.value) {`

Comment: Try removing your try catch statement. If you don't suppress error messages, you might get a clue to what is wrong. Secondly, don't use `return false` in your select label. That might just be your issue. That aside, if you want to halt an action you should call the preventDefault method of the action event. E.g. `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#hidden_applinput_' + applid).val('');
```

The code snippet above fails as `applid` is undefined in the current scope, i.e. the change event handler. In your case, you have suppressed all errors by adding the try..catch block, due to which there's no error in the js console.

Your change event handler should look something like this:

```
change: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            this.value = '';
            app_selid = this.id.split("_");
            applid = app_selid[1];
            $('#hidden_applinput_' + applid).val('');
            }
        else{
         // return your label here
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand your question, but I do think the change function could be the problem.  Have you tried setting the value on the change function?  Here is what I would try first based on what I see so far:

```
    change: function (event, ui) {
        app_selid = this.id.split("_");
        applid = app_selid[1];
        if (!ui.item) {
            this.value = '';
            $('#hidden_applinput_' + applid).val('');
            }
        else{
            // DO THE ASSIGNMENT HERE ON CHANGE
            $('#hidden_applinput_' + applid).val(ui.item.value);
        }
    }
```